# Is there a way for changing text file names in a folder using C++

Tags: c++, directory, rename, txt

I am working with a bunch of txt files(thousands) on my project. Each txt file has 'csv' information on it. The problem is that each txt file has a random name and I cannot create a code for loading them in my project due to it. So, I want to rename them in a particular pattern to make easier the loading of the files in my work. I will use C++ for accomplish this task.

I put all the txt files in a folder but I cannot see a way of renaming them using C++. How can I do this? is there a way to do it? Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure that C++ is the most adequate tool for this task ? Is there a particular reason you have to use it ? Why not a bash script ?

Comment: I am trying to use C++ because is the language which I moderately known but if there is other option like using Python I'm open to try it. A bash script could be a good option but I do not know how to do it. Can you suggest how to, please?

Comment: ok, i posted an answer for your question. I don't think C++ is the easiest way to do that. You should probably edit your question so the community can come with the easiest solution to your problem :) Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and `std::filesystem::rename` (c++17), as documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Comment: i did not know these functions, thanks ! I guess I still have to go through all C++17 ^^ I love the idea of directory_iterator :D

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer

This answer validity is based on a comment where the author precised they were not bound to the C++ language (it may be worth editing the question, the C++ tag, and the OS). This solution may work for UNIX systems supporting bash, that is most Linux distributions and all releases of Apple's macOS prior to macOS Catalina (correct me if I'm wrong).

## Bash command line

Using the following bash command should rename all the files in a folder with increasing numbers, that is:

- toto.csv -> 1.csv
- titi.csv -> 2.csv etc

It assumes the ordering is not important.

```
a=1; for i in *; do mv -n "$i" "$a.csv" ; let "a +=1"; done
```

To test it, you can prepare a test folder by opening a terminal and typing:

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch toto.csv titi.csv tata.csv
ls
```

**Output:**

```
tata.csv  titi.csv  toto.csv
```

Then you can run the following command:

```
a=1; for i in *; do mv -n "$i" "$a.csv" ; let "a +=1"; done
ls
```

**Output:**

```
1.csv  2.csv  3.csv
```

## Explication:

- `a=1` declare a variable
- `for i in *;` begin to iterate over all files in the folder
- `do mv` will move (rename) a file of the list (that is, the variable `$i`) to a new name called `a.csv`
- and we increment the counter `a`, and close the loop.
- the option `-n` will make sure no file gets overwritten by the command `mv`

I assumed there was no specific criterion to rename the files. If there is a specific structure (pattern) in the renaming, the bash command can probably accommodate it, but the question should then give more details about these requirements :)